# If there are no sdks available for the payment integration , can i use there curl api to do so?

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, payment, adyen

I wanted to integrate one of the Payment Gateways called Adyen in my flutter application , sadly they dont offer sdk or any library for flutter .
But they do offer support to make payment using APIs (curl,python, node js)
Can I use http package to call these apis .
Moreover , they offer support for java , alternatively can I implement the sdk in native java and then use platform channel to call that java code.
Which one is better ?
Thank you !!!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adyen platform offers REST [APIs](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/) to perform payments and other operations.
The various Adyen [SDKs](https://github.com/adyen) simplify the integration allowing developers to use their favourite language, however, you can use the technology you want (Flutter, Rust, etc..) and perform the HTTP calls, parse the JSON responses, etc..

For Java-based integration, the [Adyen Java](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-java-api-library) library provides everything you really need: a method for each API call, classes that map requests and responses, security, logging, and error handling. Several [examples](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-java-spring-online-payments/tree/main) are also made available.

Both approaches are valid and the choice depends on the trade-off between the extra complexity of adding a Java component against the simplicity of integration.

Comment: Yes i was thinking of using the http calls for the same , cuz I dont know how much sense will calling native for every other step will make .